# OUTPUGet street1 and street 2 Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9

How I can get street address 1 and street address 2 value. I create an extension and I want to get street address in Magento. In the block I have this function:

```
public function updateFormData() {
    $data = $this->getData('form_data');
    if (is_null($data)) {
        /** @var array $formData */
        $formData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerFormData(true);
        $order = $this->getOrder();
        $address = $order->getShippingAddress();
        $customerData = [
            'email' => $order->getCustomerEmail(),
            'firstname' => $order->getCustomerFirstname(),
            'lastname' => $order->getCustomerLastname(),
            'city' => $order->getBillingAddress()->getCity(),
            'country' => $order->getBillingAddress()->getCountry(),
            'telephone' => $order->getBillingAddress()->getTelephone(),
            'company' => $order->getBillingAddress()->getCompany(),
        ];

        $data = new Varien_Object();
        if ($formData) {
            $data->addData($formData);
            $data->setCustomerData(1);
        }
        $data->addData($customerData);
        if (isset($data['region_id'])) {
            $data['region_id'] = (int)$data['region_id'];
        }
        $this->setData('form_data', $data);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

and in the phtml file I add this:

```
       <?php $_streetValidationClass = $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('street'); ?>
            <li class="wide">
                <label for="street_1" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Street Address') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="text" name="street[]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getStreet(1)) ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Street Address')) ?>" id="street_1" class="input-text <?php echo $_streetValidationClass ?>" />
                </div>
            </li>
        <?php $_streetValidationClass = trim(str_replace('required-entry', '', $_streetValidationClass)); ?>
        <?php for ($_i = 2, $_n = $this->helper('customer/address')->getStreetLines(); $_i <= $_n; $_i++): ?>
            <li class="wide">
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="text" name="street[]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getStreet($_i)) ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Street Address %s', $_i)) ?>" id="street_<?php echo $_i ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $_streetValidationClass ?>" />
                </div>
            </li>
        <?php endfor; ?>
```

I try to add this                   **`'street_1' => $order->getBillingAddress()->getData('street'),`**
But always street_1 address value is blank. I try to get all fields in the order success page.

OUTPUT:

```
<li class="wide">
<label class="required" for="street_1">
<div class="input-box">
<input id="street_1" class="input-text required-entry" type="text" title="Street Address" value="address1 address2" name="street[]">
</div>
</li>
<li class="wide">
<div class="input-box">
<input id="street_2" class="input-text " type="text" title="Street Address 2" value="" name="street[]">
</div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$order->getBillingAddress()->getData('street')` will return an array.
So you can access the data with:

```
$billingStreet  = $order->getBillingAddress()->getData('street');
$billingStreet1 = $billingStreet[0];
$billingStreet2 = $billingStreet[1];
$billingStreet3 = $billingStreet[2];
```

*edit*: the code above is to get the billing address of an order, what I think you want now is actually the new address, the data set in the form. So this should give you the information you're after, as long as you put it before the `$data = new Varien_Object();` line:

```
$streetArray = $data['street'];
$street1     = $streetArray[0];
$street2     = $streetArray[1];
```

so your function will be:

```
public function updateFormData() {
    $data = $this->getData('form_data');
    if (is_null($data)) {
        /** @var array $formData */
        $formData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerFormData(true);
        $order = $this->getOrder();
        $address = $order->getShippingAddress();
        $streetArray = $data['street'];
        $street1     = $streetArray[0];
        $street2     = $streetArray[1];
        $customerData = [
            'email' => $order->getCustomerEmail(),
            'firstname' => $order->getCustomerFirstname(),
            'lastname' => $order->getCustomerLastname(),
            'city' => $order->getBillingAddress()->getCity(),
            'country' => $order->getBillingAddress()->getCountry(),
            'telephone' => $order->getBillingAddress()->getTelephone(),
            'company' => $order->getBillingAddress()->getCompany(),
            'street_1' => $street1,
            'street_2' => $street2
        ];

        $data = new Varien_Object();
        if ($formData) {
            $data->addData($formData);
            $data->setCustomerData(1);
        }
        $data->addData($customerData);
        if (isset($data['region_id'])) {
            $data['region_id'] = (int)$data['region_id'];
        }
        $this->setData('form_data', $data);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: thank you, is the same leike before value="", mean blank

Comment: please tell me something how is look this in that public function in the $customerData = []?

Comment: I just ask you how we can put your condition in my code? where I neeed to put your code to solve the street value?

Comment: thank you OSdave for your help, please take a look here the second adreess line not have the value, but in the first are both address: 
street_1:
value="address1 address2"
I update my post and I put my output there, you can see that the street_2 value is blank
street_2
and for street_2 value=""